# mcrypt installed but laravel throwing error on install

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, wamp, mcrypt

so I have been looking for 12 hours now for a solution to this error I am getting when trying to install Laravel framework for php. I have found many different posts about it but none seems to work. Heres the issue, I go through all the steps to get Laravel on my computer, which is downloading and installing composer to my /usr/local/bin/ directory and then running this command:

```
Desktop $ composer create-project laravel/laravel learning-laravel
```

and I get this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Installation request for laravel/framework v5.0.16 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.16].
- laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
```

I have deleted and reinstalled php, I have ran a script seeing if mcrypt is installed and it runs true, I have tried adding extension=mcrypt.so to the php.ini file (perhaps in the wrong place in the file) but nothing seems to work. I am not working with MAMP I have my own local testing environment.

I am running Mavericks

I have php 5.6.6 installed

I am running apache 2.2.26

Comment: Are you sure you are modifying the correct php.ini?  Sometimes it's possible that the php running in the command line is not the same as the one being used by the webserver.  This is usually the case with WAMP.

Comment: Does mcrypt appear in `phpinfo()`?

Comment: @Machavity Yes phpinfo() says mcrypt is enabled

Comment: @user3158900 I can't seem to find any other php.ini files, is there a way to check where composer is going to use the php.ini file?

Comment: Just to make sure, type `php -m` into the command line and see if it lists mcrypt

Comment: @user3158900 it doesn't list it, what does that mean and what should I do to get it listed?

Comment: That means your webserver is using a different instance of php than the command line or they are loading up different config files.  The command `php --ini` should let you know where the configuration file is being loaded that you will need to change

Comment: @user3158900 o gotcha theres a couple of them in there, php.ini.default, php.ini-5.2-previous, php-fpm.conf.default, php.ini.default-5.2-previous. Can I just add the php.ini file that my webserver is using to this directory and it will override all the files i just listed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mac but it looks like you can just `sudo cp php.ini.default php.ini`.  It's probably explained better here in the section titled `php.ini`.  http://akrabat.com/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-mavericks/

Comment: @user3158900 alright, so I did all of that and it still isn't showing mcrypt when I run php -m.

Comment: @user3158900 Never mind, figured it out, thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem with mcrypt and the laravel framework running on my mac. I am running php 5.6.6. The mcrypt module seemed to be enabled after viewing phpinfo(). The command line "php -v" command showed that the default version was php 5.4 I think. I added php5 to my bash profile by

1) Get into your user root folder:

```
cd ~yourUsername
```

2) Edit your bash profile

```
sudo nano .bash_profile
```

2) add the line:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH"
```

This worked for me. Please correct me if I am wrong, but I think for whatever reason the default version of php was being used with incorrect mcrypt configurations. This changed the version of php being used from the command line, and fixed the problem. Now when I type "php -v" the correct version php 5.6.6 show up. Haven't had an issue with mcrypt since.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu it's the following two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/
```

Comment: This worked for me! I didn't have the php5-mcrypt package installed, but I already had php5 in my $PATH variable, as suggested by the above accepted answer.